# How am i missing last element of an array

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am facing a problem with

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool check(int input)
{
    int count = 0;
    int temp;
    int val[] = { 2,0,2,1 };
    temp = input;
    while (temp != 0) {
        count++;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    int *arr = new int[count];
    for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    temp = 0;
    int res = count;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < res; k++)
        {
            if (val[j] == arr[k])
            {
                cout << "CHECKING : " << arr[k] << endl;;
                j = j + 1;
                for (int l = k; l < (count - 1); l++)
                {
                    arr[l] = arr[l + 1];
                }
                res=res-1;
                temp++;
                k = 0;
                if (temp == 4)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << temp;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    if (check(input) == true)
    {
        cout <<endl << "YES!!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<endl <<"NO!!" << endl;
    }
}
```

this program I have to check if input number have 2021 number or not if input is 2002021 output should be yes or input is 2002024 output should be no because  1(2021) is missing now the thing is my program works fine logically but i dont know how my array last element is missing like if i put 200022021 = then the output will be no but if I am giving 200022012 it is saying yes i dont know how my last element of array is missing.

Comment: If you do `new int[count]` the highest index you can access in that new array is `count - 1`. If `count` is 5 the array has 5 `int`s at indices 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. By doing `arr[i]` where `i == count` you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)` should be `for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)`. You probably should verify that j < 4 here: `if (val[j] == arr[k])`

Comment: j=4* corrected but still same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the loop counter wrong:

```
for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
{
    arr[i] = input % 10;
    input /= 10;
}
```

In the first iteration `i == count` and `arr[count]` is out-of-bounds. Last iteration `i == 1` (because when `(i >= 0) == false` you stop the loop) and you never assign to `arr[0]`.

You can call such mistakes history when you use either `std::vector` or `std::array` (for dynamic / fixed size, resp.) and use their reverse iterators (`rbegin` and `rend`) to iterate all elements in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I can't be bothered looking for the bug:

You can use the same method as you do for separating the single digits to examine the number in groups of four digits.

`x % 10` is the last digit; `x % 100` is the last two digits; `x % 1000` is the last three digits, and so on.
Add a division by 10 to "shift" the number:

```
bool check(int input)
{
    while (input > 2020)
    {
        if (input % 10000 == 2021)
        {
            return true;
        }
        input /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```